# Hopficity of Baumslag-Solitar groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

I am struggling to find the exact source (with proofs) of the following ''well-known'' statement:

*the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(m,n)=\langle a,t \mid ta^m t^{-1}=a^n\rangle$ is Hopfian if and only if either $m=\pm 1$ or $n=\pm 1$ or $\pi(m)=\pi(n)$, where $\pi(m)$ denotes the set of all primes dividing $m$.*

This fact is commonly attributed to Collins and Levin [*Collins, Donald J.; Levin, Frank*, [**Automorphisms and Hopficity of certain Baumslag-Solitar groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01192801), Arch. Math. 40, 385-400 (1983). [ZBL0498.20021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0498.20021).]. However, that paper seems to primarily deal with the case when either $m$ divides $n$ or $n$ divides $m$. So, my question is

**Where can I find the first published proof of the following theorem?**

Theorem: *if $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\pi(m)=\pi(n)$ and neither $m$ divides $n$ nor $n$ divides $m$ then $BS(m,n)$ is Hopfian.*

In particular,

**Who was the first to prove that $BS(12,18)$ is Hopfian?**

Collins and Levin seem to attribute this theorem to Meskin [*Meskin, Stephen*, [**Nonresidually finite one-relator groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995962), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 164, 105-114 (1972). [ZBL0245.20028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0245.20028).].
But I do not actually see any proofs of Hopficity in Meskin's paper, covering the desired non-residually finite case.

P.S. The earliest published proof I could find is in [*Andreadakis, S.; Raptis, E.; Varsos, D.*, [**Hopficity of certain HNN-extensions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927879208824417), Commun. Algebra 20, No. 5, 1511-1533 (1992). [ZBL0792.20024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0792.20024).], where the authors consider a more general class of HNN-extensions of abelian groups and deduce the above theorem as a special case. Note that this is 30 years after the result was announced by Baumslag and Solitar and 14 years after Collins' paper where he attributes it to Meskin...

PPS: [link](https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-68/issue-3/Some-two-generator-one-relator-non-Hopfian-groups/bams/1183524561.full) to the original paper by Baumslag and Solitar *(Some two-generator one-relator non-Hopfian groups. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 68 (1962), 199–201.)*

Comment: There might be information here: Collins (Donald J.). – Some one-relator Hopfian groups. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 235, 1978, pp. 363–374. [Link at AMS page](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-235-00/S0002-9947-1978-0460468-4/)

Comment: @YCor: I know of this paper, but I do not see a proof in it. Again, it seems to attribute the statement to Baumslag-Solitar/Meskin. Also, this paper contains mistakes, as discussed by Collins-Levin.

Comment: There is a proof in E. Souche's thesis (2001).

Comment: Hopficity... what a great word coining! How would M. Hopf have felt about it? :)

Comment: @Wolfgang: I think this term has become more or less standard nowadays.

Comment: Of course, I think so... but imagine e.g. the bunyakovskivisity of something^^...

Comment: @Wolfgang Isn't the Hopf in question Heinz Hopf?

Comment: @shane.orourke Yes, but I read it as Monsieur Hopf, which seems likely given Wolfgang's location!

Comment: Chandler & Magnus (my current bedtime reading :)) say (on p. 120) that BS(12,18) is proved to be Hopfian in the 1962 paper of Baumslag & Solitar that introduces the eponymous groups. I don’t have the Baumslag—Solitar paper to hand, but that appears to resolve your second question.

Comment: @HJRW The 1962 Baumslag-Solitar paper is only a Bulletin article, and contains no proofs. It also contains incorrect statements about which BS groups are residually finite.

Comment: Indeed it seems it was widely believed that these statements were proved in the original 1962 BS paper, which contains only statements and a short sketch of proof of one of them. I added the link to this original paper in the post.